# Scheme - find most deeply values nested lists

Tags: scheme

I asked several days ago about finding the [most deeply nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355428/scheme-find-most-deeply-nested-lists/8360899#8360899). I implemented the idea that was given, and it works.

But there is another problem: I also need to build a list from the nested list. meaning: If I change `(8)` and `(10 11 12)`, to leaf1 and leaf2, I need to return: `'(ans (leaf1 (8)) (leaf2 (10 11 12))`. /ans is a quote

In other words:
my function will get
`(1 (2 3) (4 (5) (7 (8) (10 11 12))))))` => the most nested lists are `(8)` and `(10 11 12)` => my function will return  `'(ans (leaf1 (8)) (leaf2 (10 11 12))`.

I am trying to find an idea, **not an implementation**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do. Currently (if I understand correctly) you have a recursive function that descends a tree and uses `cons` to build a modified copy (in which the most deeply-nested lists are replaced with something). This is a common pattern for tree-recursive functions, but there's no reason they have to return a value with a similar structure to the input they recur on. For example, you could write a function to walk a tree of numbers and return their sum.

In this case it sounds like you probably want to keep the basic structure of your tree-recursive function, but use `cons` or possibly `append` to build a *flat* list of the most-deeply-nested-lists you've found.

I can't quite tell from your question, but you might also be looking for a way to write a function that returns *two* separate values: one being the tree with deeply-nested-lists replaced by something else, and the other being the flat list of the replaced bits themselves. In this case you might want to look into the Scheme procedures `values` and `call-with-values`, and maybe the library form `let-values` if your Scheme has it. See the Schemewiki FAQ [here](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language) for more info (scroll down).

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. I build procedure thar replace the most nested value in a list. But the big problem, that this is a recursive method, so I cant build a new list from this method, and only change it. I didn't understand the use of call-with-values in this question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AdamSh: you certainly can build a new list in a recursive function: that's how most of the standard functions like `map` and `filter` work. It's hard to give better advice without seeing your code, but here are two toy problems which might be helpful: (1) write a function to take a tree of integers and return a similar tree with each number doubled (*without* modifying the original tree); (2) modify this function to add up all the numbers instead, or make a flat list of them. If you have trouble with this, I'd suggest getting a copy of _The Little Schemer_ and working through it. Good luck!